# 正規表現(GNU grep)の先読みでn個後をマッチ対象にするには？

Tags: 正規表現, bash, grep

次のような文字列があるとします

```
Hello!How are you?Good bye!
```

例えば、「`ll`」から3つ後の「`o`」、つまりこの場合であれば「`o!How are y`」をマッチ対象とするといったようなことを行いたいです。

`grep -P "(?<=ll).*(?=o)`だともちろん「`o!How are you?Go`」までがマッチ対象になりますし、`grep -P "(?<=ll).*?(?=o)`とすると、「`o!H`」の部分だけがマッチ対象となってしまいます。数字を指定し、その数だけ後の文字列までをマッチ対象としたいです。

ご存知の方がおられましたらご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: シェルスクリプト上で行うため、grepだけでは不可能な場合、bashの機能や別のコマンドを利用しても問題ありません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ echo 'Hello!How are you?Good bye!' | grep -Po '(?<=ll)([^o]*o){2}[^o]*(?=o)'
o!How are y
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！行いたいことが実現できました。